# Check whether non-index column sorted in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to test whether a dataframe is sorted by a given column that's not an index (i.e. is there an equivalent to is_monotonic() for non-index columns) without calling a sort all over again, and without converting a column into an index?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are a handful of functions in `pd.algos` which might be of use. They're all undocumented implementation details, so they might change from release to release:

```
>>> pd.algos.is[TAB]
pd.algos.is_lexsorted          pd.algos.is_monotonic_float64  pd.algos.is_monotonic_object
pd.algos.is_monotonic_bool     pd.algos.is_monotonic_int32
pd.algos.is_monotonic_float32  pd.algos.is_monotonic_int64
```

The `is_monotonic_*` functions take an array of the specified dtype and a "timelike" boolean that should be `False` for most use cases. (Pandas sets it to `True` for a case involving times represented as integers.) The return value is a tuple whose first element represents whether the array is monotonically non-decreasing, and whose second element represents whether the array is monotonically non-increasing. Other tuple elements are version-dependent:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,2], "B": [2,3,1]})
>>> pd.algos.is_monotonic_int64(df.A.values, False)[0]
True
>>> pd.algos.is_monotonic_int64(df.B.values, False)[0]
False
```

All these functions assume a specific input dtype, even `is_lexsorted`, which assumes the input is a list of `int64` arrays. Pass it the wrong dtype, and it gets really confused:

```
In [32]: pandas.algos.is_lexsorted([np.array([-2, -1], dtype=np.int64)])
Out[32]: True
In [33]: pandas.algos.is_lexsorted([np.array([-2, -1], dtype=float)])
Out[33]: False
In [34]: pandas.algos.is_lexsorted([np.array([-1, -2, 0], dtype=float)])
Out[34]: True
```

I'm not entirely sure why Series don't already have some kind of short-circuiting `is_sorted`.  There might be something which makes it trickier than it seems.

Comment: Amazing both for pointed me to this pd.algos library, and for the tip! Any chance you know any easy way to deal with descending sorts? I want it sorted so I can pull first (largest) row. I can just call len() and get the last row if needed, just looking for speed.

Comment: @nick_eu: not really, I'm afraid.  You can always use `.iloc[-1]` to get the last row, though.

Comment: With `z = numpy.array([1., 2.])`, both `pandas.algos.is_lexsorted([z])` and `pandas.algos.is_lexsorted([-z])` return `True` in my tests. Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/algos.pyx#L959), it seems to assume 64-bit signed integer inputs; it doesn't actually work for arbitrary dtypes.

Comment: Looks like this is now at `pandas._libs.algos.is_lexsorted`.  And a note, it does require `int64` dtype

Comment: pandas.algos is now private and deprecated: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/whatsnew.html

Answer (score 62):

Meanwhile, since 0.19.0, there is `pandas.Series.is_monotonic_increasing`, `pandas.Series.is_monotonic_decreasing`, and `pandas.Series.is_monotonic`.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the numpy method:

```
import numpy as np

def is_df_sorted(df, colname):
    return (np.diff(df[colname]) > 0).all()
```

A more direct approach (like you suggested, but you say you don't want it..) is to convert to an index and use the `is_monotonic` property:

```
import pandas as pd

def is_df_sorted(df, colname):
    return pd.Index(df[colname]).is_monotonic
```

Comment: Thanks shx2! That meeds my goal, but turns out: <code>     assert(df.column.diff()[1:] <= 0).all() </code> (first value of diff is a NaN) is slower than just sorting with a mergesort. Also, is_monotonic()  doesn't tolerate weakly monotonic columns, so doesn't work in my case. :/ But maybe on a bigger dataset diff would payoff.

Comment: @nick_eu: ah, sorry, I meant that for shx2; I think it needs to be `>= 0` instead of `> 0`, otherwise `[1, 2, 2]` won't give the same answer as `is_monotonic`.