# what is the quickest way to determine if an array is sorted?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

This may seem like a duplicate of [Check whether non-index column sorted in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419877/check-whether-non-index-column-sorted-in-pandas)

I read that post and all the answers.  No one (save one answer) addresses using numpy.  It's all focused on python lists.  By asking a similar question with the `numpy` tag, I believe I'll get a different class of answers.  That said, on to the question.

---

consider two arrays `a` and `b`.  `b` is sorted while `a` is not.

```
a = np.array([2, 1, 3, 0])

b = np.arange(4)
```

I've written this function to determine sorted-ness

```
def is_sorted(x):
    return (np.arange(len(x)) == np.argsort(x)).all()
```

What else can I do to improve on this idea?  What is the quickest `pandas` or `numpy` algorithm to determine if a `pd.Series` or `np.ndarray` is sorted?

---

```
is_sorted(a)

False
```

---

```
is_sorted(b)

True
```

---

Comment: some pandas algorithms mentioned here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28419877/check-whether-non-index-column-sorted-in-pandas  (I'm not saying it's a duplicate, just seems to have  some good suggestions)

Comment: Those are handy!  Thanks for that link.

Comment: How are `(np.diff(a)>0).all()` and `(np.diff(b)>0).all()`? The only issue would be reverse ordering. But I think `np.abs(np.diff(a)>0).all()` should be fine?

Comment: @Abdou I saw that in JohnE's link.  I'll test it out and report back with results of various suggestions.

Comment: I'd go with `(x[1:] >= x[:-1]).all()`.

Comment: Most of the ad-hoc solutions fail if there are NaNs in the data.  `pd.algos.is_lexsorted()` does not fail in this case.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate because the performance aspect (_fastest way_) isn't actually covered in the supposed duplicate.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: NaNs are unordered, so the concept of whether an array containing NaNs is sorted isn't even well-defined.

Comment: @user2357112: Sorting NaN values is perfectly well defined in NumPy and Pandas.

Comment: @JohnZwinck: If your concept of "is sorted" is "in the order that `numpy.sort` would produce", then you might need NaN handling. If your concept of "is sorted" is based on the the natural ordering of floating-point numbers, then NaN inputs don't really make sense. Also, I don't think `pandas.algos.is_lexsorted` does what you think it does. For example, `pandas.algos.is_lexsorted([z])` and `pandas.algos.is_lexsorted([-z])` are both `True` when `z` is `numpy.array([1., 2.])`.

Comment: `pandas.algos.is_lexsorted` actually assumes 64-bit signed integer input. With how IEEE floating-point works, that means it happens to "work" for 64-bit NaNs, but it fails on negative floating-point input. It is not a solution here.

Answer (score 4):

it is O(nlogn) to sort an array, but to tell if an array is already sorted it only takes O(n).

```
is_sorted = lambda x: (np.diff(x)>=0).all()
```

Comment: appreciate the add big O info!

Comment: This fails if there are NaN values.

Comment: You just break it into two steps: 1) is the array sortable? 2) if so, is it sorted?

Comment: After looking into `pd.algos.is_lexsorted` I'm happy with this being a dup.  `is_lexsorted` is very fast.